# How to check when was the successful build happened using maven commands

Tags: java, maven

In our daily routine we are checking out lots of projects and trying to build using `mvn clean install` to verify failures in the build process.

Sometimes we are missing how many builds already finished successfully and how many are yet to complete. It would be very useful for us if I could find a command which is used to get the last successful build details like when it is done etc. It will help lots of my time.

What I need is a command that should tell me the last successful build time of the work space.

Comment: Looks like @user is right - you're reinventing Continuous Integration.

Comment: Thank you for the assurance, @AleksandrM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems as though you reinvented [Continuous Integration.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) A free, open-source tool is [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/). They have some [introduction on the website](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Introduction).

In short: you have a server which regularly (or after each commit) checks out the sources, builds them, runs tests, etc., to see if they work OK.

Comment: Exactly what I need is a command, that should tell me the last successful build time of work space.

Comment: For local development a Jenkins Server is too much. Therefore the answer of @Wouter is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using linux, the following command line greps out the timestamp at the end of the build:

```
mvn clean install | grep '\[INFO\] Finished at' | sed 's/^\[INFO\] Finished at: //g'
```

The output looks like:

```
2016-01-06T13:46:14+01:00
```

The same trick can also be used for Total time, for instance:

```
mvn clean install | grep '\[INFO\] Total time' | sed 's/^\[INFO\] Total time: //g'
```

And this output looks like:

```
0.060 s
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I second what @user have suggested: this is a job for a Continuous Integration server, and Jenkins can get you started very quickly on that. Even if you don't want all the bells and whistles, you can at least use it for tracking success and failure. Don't be intimidated by the new concept: it should be as easy as downloading a single WAR file from Jenkins download site, and starting it, then connecting from the browser and configuring a minimal job.

But in the case that you have other legacy requirements and are unable to use Jenkins, I would suggest using "gmaven" plugin to run a groovy script that would allow you to run custom logic at the end of the job. You can use this for example to write a timestamp and a status code to a file in the local folder.

Of course, this would get you forward, but it won't replace a real CI set up. The suggestions that I provided would allow you to track the success of some pre-defined sets of build commands (we have to bind gmaven to specific lifecycle phases). This proposal will also suffer from not being able to track job failures.

Another suggestion would be to write a custom shell script (Bash or Windows, depending on your OS), that would run the actual maven command, passing it all the command line arguments, then at the end would check the return status from maven, and write the success/failure status (and timestamp) to a local log file. This would be a question to ask in the scripting area, and the actual solution would depend on the actual OS.